# SyntaxError: cannot import name 'mnist' from 'keras.datasets'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to import mnist but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kumat\OneDrive\desktop\DCGAN.py", line 9, in <module>
    from keras.datasets import mnist
  File "C:\Users\kumat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2
  File "C:\Users\kumat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\kumat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\kumat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\kumat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The import is invoked here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Activation, BatchNormalization, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam #from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import load_model
```

Any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: That code was written before `async` was a keyword in Python…?! Which probably means you should update that library to a recent non-ancient version?

Comment: Newer versions of Python made `async` a keyword, and do not allow putting `async` in a function signature like that.